# React JS material-table autogenerate value of a column based on values of two other columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

[image]

I want to render the **Value** column data by multiplying **Quantity** and **List Price**.

[image]

And I found a way to do so. but when I console log the **data** (**data** is the array given to material-table data prop) in material-table it doesn't show a field called **Value**. Which means even though we can see **Value** in material-table it doesn't get pushed into the **data** array. Below is an image of the console log.

[image: Image of console.log]

Can someone please help me. I want the data array to be updated with the value of **Value**.

```js
columns = {
  [{
      title: "Prod. ID",
      field: "productid",
      editComponent: props => ( <
        Autocomplete options = {
          selectedProductOptions
        }
        getOptionLabel = {
          (option) => option.productid
        }
        inputValue = {
          props.value || ''
        }
        onChange = {
          e => props.onChange(e.target.innerText)
        }
        renderInput = {
          (params) =>
          <
          MuiTextField { ...params
          }
          helperText = {
            props.helperText
          }
          error = {
            props.error
          }
          variant = "standard" /
          >
        }
        />
      ),
      validate: (rowData) => (
        rowData.productid === undefined ?
        {
          isValid: false,
          helperText: 'Required *'
        } :
        rowData.productid === '' ?
        {
          isValid: false,
          helperText: 'Required *'
        } :
        true
      ),
    },
    {
      title: "Description",
      field: "description",
      editComponent: props => ( <
        Autocomplete options = {
          selectedProductOptions
        }
        getOptionLabel = {
          (option) => option.name
        }
        onChange = {
          e => props.onChange(e.target.innerText)
        }
        inputValue = {
          props.value || ''
        }
        renderInput = {
          (params) =>
          <
          MuiTextField { ...params
          }
          helperText = {
            props.helperText
          }
          error = {
            props.error
          }
          variant = "standard" /
          >
        }
        />
      ),
      validate: (rowData) =>
        rowData.description === undefined ?
        {
          isValid: false,
          helperText: 'Required *'
        } :
        rowData.description === '' ?
        {
          isValid: false,
          helperText: 'Required *'
        } :
        true

    },
    {
      title: "Unit",
      field: "unit",
      lookup: {
        Case: 'Case',
        Pieces: 'Pieces'
      },
      width: 'min-content',
      validate: (rowData) =>
        rowData.unit === undefined ?
        {
          isValid: false,
          helperText: 'Required *'
        } :
        rowData.unit === '' ?
        {
          isValid: false,
          helperText: 'Required *'
        } :
        true

    },
    {
      title: "Quantity",
      field: "quantity",
      type: 'numeric',
      cellStyle: {
        cellWidth: 'min-content'
      },
      validate: (rowData) =>
        rowData.quantity === undefined ?
        {
          isValid: false,
          helperText: 'Required *'
        } :
        rowData.quantity === '' ?
        {
          isValid: false,
          helperText: 'Required *'
        } :
        true
    },
    {
      title: "List Price (Rs.)",
      field: "listprice",
      type: 'numeric',
      cellStyle: {
        cellWidth: 'min-content'
      },
      validate: (rowData) =>
        rowData.listprice === undefined ?
        {
          isValid: false,
          helperText: 'Required *'
        } :
        rowData.listprice === '' ?
        {
          isValid: false,
          helperText: 'Required *'
        } :
        true
    },
    {
      title: "Value (Rs.)",
      field: "value",
      type: 'numeric',
      cellStyle: {
        width: 'min-content'
      },
      editable: 'never',
      render: rowData => rowData.quantity * rowData.listprice,
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: is the code not enough? there are 7 views but no answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
{
  title: "Quantity",
  field: "quantity",
  type: 'numeric',
  cellStyle: {
    cellWidth: 'min-content'
  },
  editComponent: props =>
    <
    MuiTextField
  onChange = {
    e => {
      var data = { ...props.rowData
      };
      data.quantity = e.target.value;
      let quantity = isNaN(data.quantity) ? 0 : data.quantity;
      let listprice = isNaN(data.listprice) ? 0 : data.listprice;
      data.value = quantity * listprice;
      props.onRowDataChange(data);
    }
  }
  helperText = {
    props.helperText
  }
  error = {
    props.error
  }
  variant = "standard" /
  > ,
  validate: (rowData) =>
    rowData.quantity === undefined ?
    {
      isValid: false,
      helperText: 'Required *'
    } :
    rowData.quantity === '' ?
    {
      isValid: false,
      helperText: 'Required *'
    } :
    true
}, {
  title: "List Price (Rs.)",
  field: "listprice",
  type: 'numeric',
  cellStyle: {
    cellWidth: 'min-content'
  },
  editComponent: props =>
    <
    MuiTextField
  onChange = {
    e => {
      var data = { ...props.rowData
      };
      data.listprice = e.target.value;
      let quantity = isNaN(data.quantity) ? 0 : data.quantity;
      let listprice = isNaN(data.listprice) ? 0 : data.listprice;
      data.value = quantity * listprice;
      props.onRowDataChange(data);
    }
  }
  helperText = {
    props.helperText
  }
  error = {
    props.error
  }
  variant = "standard" /
  > ,
  validate: (rowData) =>
    rowData.listprice === undefined ?
    {
      isValid: false,
      helperText: 'Required *'
    } :
    rowData.listprice === '' ?
    {
      isValid: false,
      helperText: 'Required *'
    } :
    true


}, {
  title: "Value (Rs.)",
  field: "value",
  type: 'numeric',
  cellStyle: {
    width: 'min-content'
  },
  editable: 'never',
}
```

I figured out the answer.

We have to use `props.onRowDataChange()`.

As u can see here we get the `rowData` from `props` and destructure it and save it in a variable called `data` (`rowData` is an object array and since we manually make changes to the `listprice` , `quantity` we insert this code here) and then we do the changes we want to do. in my case I wanted to get the value by multiplying quantity and listprice. Once the changes are done. we are gonna pass the new data to `props.onRowDataChange()`.

If u need more explaining be free to ask.

This is where I got the answer from https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/615